# Put data in c3 charts

Tags: javascript, python, css, django, c3.js

I have strange problem with put data to chart.
I have list `month_with_earnings_list = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 18, 386, 0, 18, 1125]` and i want use this date to make bar chart but when i try in this way my chart is empty:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
bindto: '#chart1',
data: {
    columns: [
        ['Monthly earnings',
        {% for value in month_with_earnings_list %}
        {{ value }},
        {% endfor %}
        ]
    ],
    type: 'bar'}});
```

But if i make:

```
  var chart = c3.generate({
bindto: '#chart1',
data: {
    columns: [
        ['Monthly earnings',0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 18, 386, 0, 18, 1125]
    ],
    type: 'bar'}});
```

Works good but i want put data from list.

Comment: Does `['Monthly earnings',0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 18, 386, 0, 18, 1125,]` works fine?  note the `,` after 1125

Comment: What does the rendered html look like?

Comment: Problem solved i made stupid mistake on back end, forgot change args value...